# What does rebooting bootloader do?

Tags: unbricking, bootloader

I recently got a OnePlus 3T, then I updated it and now it's bricked. I cannot access recovery mode. I figured out how to get to a screen where I can reboot the bootloader. What does it do? Will it fix my problem